# How to combine two tables/view objects into one in JDeveloper?

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have the following tables/view objects:

**StudentRequest**
**StudentApprovedRequests**

I want to add a new **StudentRequestHistory** View object that simply combines both of these tables by displaying both of their content in one. This table is simply for visual/front end purposes, its does not exist in the database.

What I want is this:

[StudentRequest View Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS6Wi.png)

[StudentApprovedRequests View Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCEGi.png)

[StudentRequestHistory View Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27dVe.png)

Really hope someone can help.
Thank you!

Comment: `UNION ALL`. Google for details

Comment: Is UNION ALL available in JDeveloper?

Comment: I've never used it. `UNION ALL` is a standard SQL operation, as long as you can execute SQL you can do it. I assume you can...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a VO based on a SQL query that uses the Union: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/develop/adf-bc-vo-queries.htm